# Grouping By One Column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Following is my sql query

```
select p.ProductID,p.PartNo,p.Description
from tblProducts p left join
     (select productid,matchingmodels
      from tblAlternates
      group by productid,matchingmodels
     ) alt
     on p.productid = alt.productid
where alt.matchingmodels like '%TYT%'
```

This is how my tblProdcuts llooks

[image]

my tblAlternates looks like this

[image]

my current result is as below

[image]

The result that i would like to see is just a single row instead of 3 rows.

The desired result is just this
[image]

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What would be on the one row?  Please show your desired results.  What database are you using?  Please tag correctly.

Comment: If you really want LEFT JOIN, move `alt.matchingmodels like '%TYT%'` to the ON clause.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT p.ProductID,p.PartNo,p.Description`...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Since in the subquery you are grouping both by "productId" and 
"matchingmodels" columns you will get duplicate values for "productId" just like you show in your question. When you do the join, it will return all the matches, hence your duplicates. Since you don't seem to need the "matchingModels" column, you could just not select it in the subquery, and that will take care of the duplicates.

```
select p.ProductID,p.PartNo,p.Description
from tblProducts p left join
     (select productid
      from tblAlternates
      where matchingmodels like '%TYT%'
      group by productid
     ) alt
     on p.productid = alt.productid
```

Or

```
select p.ProductID,p.PartNo,p.Description
from tblProducts p left join
     (select DISTINCT productid
      from tblAlternates  
       where matchingmodels like '%TYT%'   
     ) alt
     on p.productid = alt.productid
```

BTW, you will need to move the "where" condition inside the subquery for this